# BigQuery streaming insert not implemented errors

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been running an app that uses streaming inserts to append data to a BigQuery table. The application has been running constantly for 5 weeks now with relatively low error rates. Between 11/01 21:40 and 12/01 00:59 about 90% of my inserts failed with the following message:

```
{
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Implemented: Streaming ingestion is disabled for the destin
ation dataset.",
    "reason" : "notImplemented"
}
```

Is there some limit that I exceeded, or some other reason?

My project number is 383840223011 in case any Google engineers are reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you streaming to tables hosted in the Europe location?

We had a configuration error for some projects in that region, and your project may have been effected. The overall outage was small, but some projects observed a high error rate. My apologies if this happened to you.

We are reviewing our configuration change process to avoid similar problems in the future.